# How to implement a typescript interface having multiple function call signatures

Tags: typescript, function, interface

```
interface SearchFunc {
  (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
 (source: string, subString: string,name:number): boolean;
}
```

Is it possible to have an interface with multiple call signatures for functions? If so, how can I implement this? Can you give me a meaningful example? Are there any use cases for this or am I thinking about / approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: In example above it would be useless, just define the `name` as optional: `name?: number)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is example:

```js
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
    (source: string, subString: string, name: number): boolean;
}

const fn: SearchFunc = (source: string, subString: string, name?: number) => true
```

But, in your case You don't need such interface.
THis technique called [overloading](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)

Overloadings are useful, if you have some constraints.

For example, your return type is dependent on third argument:

```js
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: string): boolean;
    (source: string, subString: string, name: number): string;
}

const fn: SearchFunc = (source: string, subString: string, name?: number) => null as any

const result = fn('sdf','sdf', 2) // string

const result1 = fn('sdf','sdf') // boolean
```

Or next:

```js
interface SearchFunc {
    (source: string, subString: number): boolean;
    (source: number, subString: string): string;

}

const fn: SearchFunc = (source: string | number, subString: string | number) => null as any

const result = fn('sdf', 2)

const result1 = fn(2, 'sdf')

const result2 = fn(2, 2) // error

const result3 = fn('2', '2') // error
```

Type of function allows `fn(2, 2)`, but insterface not. Interface `SearchFunc` has higher priority here.

Typed arguments: `(source: string | number, subString: string | number)` just should be compatible with interface.

Because, according to interface `source` argument could be either string or number, we should also define it in function signature as `string` | (or) `number`

Comment: const result2 = fn(2, 2) // error

const result3 = fn('2', '2') // error.. why this two are errors.The above function is having call signature with four possible combination know. Actually I am new to this symbol "I"  i am having trouble understanding that

Comment: @somanraj I made an update . More info you will find in docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads

Comment: you are superb.Your addition to answer makes more meaning